# 2.4.1: Elasticsearch/MySQL memory spikes leading to SWAP

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

Low traffic site on 2.4.1, elasticsearch, 16GB RAM, but memory usage seems to climb constantly, with CPU usage spiking, until mysql and elastic are basically running in SWAP.  Site was running fine on 2.3 but has been having these issues since upgrade.  I've seen issues like this on another site too but not sure the cause on there either

Elastic has been set to not use SWAP but there are about 90 elastic processes running which seems excessive.

Any thoughts?

contents of /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

`bootstrap.memory_lock: true` was added yesterday, but does not seem to have made any difference

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'`:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 8,
  "active_shards" : 8,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 8,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

`jvm.options` (note, I did not set this up):

```
## JVM configuration

################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## You should always set the min and max JVM heap
## size to the same value. For example, to set
## the heap to 4 GB, set:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################

# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms256m
-Xmx512m

################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below this section are considered
## expert settings. Don't tamper with them unless
## you understand what you are doing
##
################################################################

## GC configuration
8-13:-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
8-13:-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
8-13:-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

## G1GC Configuration
# NOTE: G1 GC is only supported on JDK version 10 or later
# to use G1GC, uncomment the next two lines and update the version on the
# following three lines to your version of the JDK
# 10-13:-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
# 10-13:-XX:-UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
14-:-XX:+UseG1GC
14-:-XX:G1ReservePercent=25
14-:-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30

## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails
# heap dumps are created in the working directory of the JVM
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps; ensure the directory exists and
# has sufficient space
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# specify an alternative path for JVM fatal error logs
-XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log

## JDK 8 GC logging
8:-XX:+PrintGCDetails
8:-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
8:-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
8:-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
8:-Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log
8:-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
8:-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32
8:-XX:GCLogFileSize=64m

# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
```

Comment: Run report using MySQL tuner - https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl.

Comment: Hey @BartZalas, I ran this and it didn't flag up anything major

Comment: Can you paste your elastic search conf yaml?

Comment: @BartZalas added to the description

Comment: Heh looks same like mine. Do you have smile/elasticsuite   in your vendor? What version of java and elasticsearch. Sometimes its a bug in version.

Comment: @BartZalas not using smile as have had terrible experiences in the past, but just installed the amasty search module including their elastic integration, and the issue is still occurring.

Elastic version 7.10.0
Java version 1.8.0_211

Comment: What about heap size in jvm.options in elasticsearch dir.

Comment: and curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty   print please this. Coming back to heap size I set this to 1G and its fine

Comment: @BartZalas:

-Xms256m
-Xmx512m

elastic heath in question description

Comment: In doc they write both this param should be same. Set them to 1G at least

Comment: Hey @BartZalas,  I've increased them both to 2G, will see how that goes, thanks!

Comment: 512m is too small for production, 2G sounds about right. This should be added as an accepted answer to assist others.

Comment: I'm not sure this ended up being the fix, but it certainly helped - in the end we had to disable the block_html cache (?!) which has settled memory usage down massively (there were other hanging pages with eventual 500 errors https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/500-Internal-server-error-randomly-after-upgrade-to-2-4-1/td-p/462787 )

Comment: @BartZalas I think I just jinxed it, server just ran out of memory again and everything's running in swap...

Comment: Good you comment about situation, I had similar issue but update to 2.4.1 helped me. In your case is opposite. How many products do you have? You could try with blackfire and paste more logs.

Comment: @BartZalas in this case the issue doesn't happen locally and I'm not able to install blackfire on the server :(

Comment: @eddhall Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.